# Conversion exception in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am dealing with stored procedures in c# and making a new stored procedure like this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_proc]
    @param1 int,
    @param2 varchar
AS
    UPDATE medicine 
    SET medicine_name='" + param2 + "' 
    WHERE medicine_id = '" + param1 +     "' 
RETURN 0
```

And I am calling this stored procedure in my code like this

```
if (selectedRow_update.Cells["ID"].Value != null)
{
    SqlCommand sto_proc =new SqlCommand("stored_proc",obj.con);
    sto_proc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sto_proc.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow_update.Cells["ID"].Value);
    sto_proc.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = selectedRow_update.Cells["Medicine Name"].Value.ToString();
    sto_proc.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I am getting an exception that `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '" + param1 + "' to data type int`.

As I have declared `param1` as `int` and passing a value that is also `int` after converting it because I am getting this value from datagridview row. Then why it is giving problem with conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `medicine_id` to the string literal `" + param1 + "`.  What you want to do is the following:

```
UPDATE medicine
SET medicine_name = @param2
WHERE medicine_id = @param1
```

Here's some more [quick reading](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/) on using parameters.  There's a lot out there; read up on SQL to learn the basics.

Comment: Or is the OP trying to put the value in quotes (`"`)?

Comment: @gunr2171:  Based on how OP is treating the `INT` parameter, I'm guessing not.

Comment: @gunr2171 more likely it was copied from a SQL concatenation in C#.

Comment: This solved my problem but i am facing one more problem...query in stored procedure is updating medicine name with single character. like if  i am replacing "abc" to "xyx" then this query is updating database with "x". Its picking first character of string from medicine name.

Comment: @MudasirRao:  If I had to guess, [the Add overload you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx) is defaulting to a length of 1.  Try using [an overload that specifies the size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @zimdanen I also tried this as i am passing 'int size' as a third variable according to an overload that specifies the size but problem still exist...:(

Comment: @MudasirRao:  What value are you passing for the size?

Comment: @zimdanen...I figured that out...actually in stored procedure arguments i was declaring medicine_name as varchar. infact it should be like this varchar(50). so by default it was initializing itself by varchar(1)...Thanks for you to be there in my problem...:)